Are questions about sports cards on topic?
I want to ask a question about how to store the mini cards in the Allen & Ginter series by topps and was wondering if that would be on topic?
It is collectable cards without a game.

That would be off topic. Per the help center our scope is focused on board (and card) games which are required to be actual games with rules:

How do we define Board Games?
Please see this meta question for the full discussion, the summary is:

Be playable on or around a table
Have objective rules of play and win conditions
Offer dynamic challenges, either through other players, randomization, or both
Be playable by hand, by human players implementing all of the rules


While some expertise related to storing card games could transfer to storing baseball cards, baseball cards themselves aren't topical.
